# Nuget restore in Visual Studio vs. Azure DevOps creates different packages.lock.json files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-pipelines-yaml, nuget-package-restore

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution that contains these projects:

DotNetLibrary

DotNetLibrary.Test

CPPLibrary

They reference each other like so:

```
DotNetLibrary.Test -> DotNetLibrary -> CPPLibrary
```

I am using the Nuget packages `RestoreLockedMode` feature.

When I generate the packages.lock.json file for DotNetLibrary.Test in Visual Studio, it looks like this:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8": {
      "MSTest.TestAdapter": {
        "type": "Direct",
        "requested": "[2.2.7, )",
        "resolved": "2.2.7",
        "contentHash": "E8seWhOKGEz4Aq6IaX6dUZGRSVYwLVy+6ZI9nq0TyHRuv54Id4Y7y/CB0KGiOUrqtygfooQm5wmpnDOW28N9Ug=="
      },
      "MSTest.TestFramework": {
        "type": "Direct",
        "requested": "[2.2.7, )",
        "resolved": "2.2.7",
        "contentHash": "qroVMzabIcbqwxtlDZriZflqs3nKpmqSVoM/Nfw9fg+F6885rrgo9R4gwmK7xxPPd8gpDrmNqqwpnyh6GMoN9g=="
      },
      "cpplibrary": {
        "type": "Project"
      },
      "DotNetLibrary": {
        "type": "Project",
        "dependencies": {
          "CPPLibrary": "[1.0.0, )"
        }
      }
    },
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8/win": {},
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8/win-x64": {},
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8/win-x86": {}
  }
}
```

When I build and restore the solution in Azure DevOps with `task: VSBuild@1`, the generated packages.lock.json file looks like this:

```
 {
      "version": 1,
      "dependencies": {
        ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8": {
          "MSTest.TestAdapter": {
            "type": "Direct",
            "requested": "[2.2.7, )",
            "resolved": "2.2.7",
            "contentHash": "E8seWhOKGEz4Aq6IaX6dUZGRSVYwLVy+6ZI9nq0TyHRuv54Id4Y7y/CB0KGiOUrqtygfooQm5wmpnDOW28N9Ug=="
          },
          "MSTest.TestFramework": {
            "type": "Direct",
            "requested": "[2.2.7, )",
            "resolved": "2.2.7",
            "contentHash": "qroVMzabIcbqwxtlDZriZflqs3nKpmqSVoM/Nfw9fg+F6885rrgo9R4gwmK7xxPPd8gpDrmNqqwpnyh6GMoN9g=="
          }
          "DotNetLibrary": {
            "type": "Project",
            "dependencies": {
              "CPPLibrary": "[1.0.0, )"
            }
          }
        },
        ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8/win": {},
        ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8/win-x64": {},
        ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8/win-x86": {}
      }
    }
```

The reference to CPPLibrary is missing. So when I turn on `RestoreLockedMode` feature, I get the error:

> Error NU1004: The project reference DotNetLibrary has changed. Current
> dependencies: None lock file's dependencies: CPPLibrary.The packages
> lock file is inconsistent with the project dependencies so restore
> can't be run in locked mode. Disable the RestoreLockedMode MSBuild
> property or pass an explicit --force-evaluate option to run restore to
> update the lock file.

As a workaround, I tried adding a project reference to CPPLibrary to DotNetLibray.Test.
But the packages.lock.json file generated by DevOps was the same as before, so the error was also the same.

Why do Visual Studio and Azure DevOps generate different project dependency graphs for the same solution? How do I fix it?

EDIT: The error has disappeared for some reason.

Looking through the list of restore settings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-properties, I stumbled on /p:RestoreUseStaticGraphEvaluation=true

and decided to try it. It worked at the moment, but I have since removed it again. (The error seems to have gone away.)

Comment: Hi, if possible, could you please share the .net version on your side and do you mean the cpp library is a C++ Class Clibrary project? :)

Comment: The error has mysteriously gone away. If it re-appears I can provide more information.